# C#: Calling parent (Base) constructor from child's constructor body

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I have an abstract class `Parent` and a derived class `Child`. I know that I can call `Parent`'s constructor inside `Child`'s constructor in the following way:

```
abstract class Parent 
{
    protected int i;
    protected Parent(int i) 
    {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

class Child : Parent 
{
    public Child(int i) : base(i) 
    {
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to pass some parameters to the `Parent` constructor right away. I would like to perform some calculations and *then* call `Parent`'s constructor using the result of such calculation as input parameters. The code "would look" something like this:

```
public class Child : Parent 
{
    public Child(int i) 
    {
        int calculation = i * 2; // Complicated operation
        base(calculation); // This line will break
    }
}
```

The second snippet is not valid C# code. Is there any way of postponing the call to `Parent`'s constructor to mimic the sentiment expressed on the second code snippet?

Comment: `base(i * 2)`?? Or, `base(ComplicatedCalculation(i))`? Of course, you should avoid complicated calculations in your constructors...

Comment: Construction only happens once. You can't call *any* (base or this) constructor after the instance has been constructed.

Comment: I understand that I could make the constructor look like `public Child(int i) : base(i * 2) {}`. The issue is that this solution would not be elegant if the calculation involved is, for instance, a long equation. Regardless, thank you for the insight.

Comment: @DanielHernandez did you just ignore the second part of Will's comment?

Comment: I apologise if I sounded like I didn't pay attention to @Will's response. I didn't refresh my browser and therefore i didn't see the edited comment. Having a function call sounds like a good idea!

Comment: Another way to handle this would be to have an `Initialize(int i)` method declared in your base class that would do the parts of initialization that can't be done in the constructor. Then your `Child` constructor simply calls `base.Initialize`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you are right, I made a type. I want to use the `calculation` variable.

Comment: I ninja edited the comment a couple times. Anyhow, the best solution would be to have a protected abstract method that provides the result of the calculation that the base class calls at the last possible moment prior to using the result. If that has to happen within the construction of the object due to the overall design.... rethink the design. One possibility is to have a protected constructor and a static factory method that performs the calculations, creates the instance, passing the result to the constructor, and returns the instance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would do the same trick assuming u can access the properties directly

```
abstract class Parent 
{
    protected int i;
    protected Parent() 
    {
       //default constructor
    }
}

class Child : Parent 
{
    public Child(int i)
    {

        Int calculation = i * 2
        base.i = calculation
    }
}
```

however if u cant do that because of restricted access to the properties my personal preference is to outsource the logic of the calculation in separate  function and call the base class like following:

```
abstract class Parent 
{
    protected int i;
    protected Parent(int i) 
    {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

class Child : Parent 
{
    public Child(int i) : base(Child.dosomework(i)) 
    {
    }

    public static int dosomework(int i){
        int calculation = i * 2
        return calculation
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the approach that I will use. I am accepting this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
abstract class Parent
{
    protected int i;
    protected Parent(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    protected Parent(Func<int> param)
    {
        i = param();
    } 
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(int i) : base(() => i * 2)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to the answer  I accepted as the correct one, so thank you. I must say that, even though this approach looks a bit cumbersome, it is the coolest looking answer for this question.

Answer (score 3):

If you were allowed to call a **base** constructor in the child class in that way, you can face weird problems in your programs. Means that you can leave that instance in an inconsistent state because you could make a try-catch to handle some input-parameter errors and bypass the constructor. That is not the idea, imagine if you were allowed to create a Date in that way.

```
class MyDate : DateTime
{
  public int(int year, int month, int day)
  {
      try
     {
        base(-1, -1, -1)
     }
     catch
    {
    }
  }
}
```

The funny thing is that Java allows that with the **super** keyword.

Comment: You are a wise man. I was subconsciously trying to replicata Java's `super()` feature. Now I see what that may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Create a static method and use `base(MyStaticMethod(params))`

Answer (score 1):

The point of a constructor is to construct the instance, i.e. get it into a valid state. It should do that and nothing else. And if your class can exist without having `i` set already, then the act of setting `i` is not essential to its validity and therefore doesn't belong in a constructor.

Perhaps you don't want inheritance, you want composition.

```
class Inner
{
    protected readonly int _i;

    public Inner(int i)
    {
        _i = i;
    }
}

class Outer
{
    protected Inner _inner = null;

    public Outer()
    {
        //Construct
    }

    public void SetI(int i)
    {
        _inner = new Inner(i);  //Call constructor of Inner
    }
}
```